# How to create a plugin/gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Whats the best guide to start working like creating a plugin/gem. I got [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/33-making-a-plugin) tutorial from railscast but this is very basic.I got some other tutorials but all of them are too basic. Any other tutorial, you can suggest.

and what the things we should kept in mind while creating a gem or plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I might be late to comment here. I found very useful tutorial here. SO. just want to share it with u.

http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

Comment: This is for gems in general, not Rails gems.

Answer (score 2):

I warmly recommend Rails Guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ - they provide *lots* of interesting tutorials.

They also have [an article about creating plugins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html).

Answer (score 1):

I just finished creating my first rails engine which I packaged as a gem. I extracted a lot of useful foundational stuff and wrote up a tutorial on getting started with it:

https://web.archive.org/web/20151008192541/http://keithschacht.com/creating-a-rails-3-engine-plugin-gem/

Comment: @Chris Please edit that link into the answer :) (Just make sure the edit comment explains why you're editing it)